# PHP get full url from two strings

Tags: php

Guys I have two Strings

```
$first = "/calvin/master/?p=pages&id=3";   //DYNAMIC URL

$second = "http://localhost/calvin/";      //BASE URL USER DECIDED
```

I want to get full url like this

```
$target = "http://localhost/calvin/master/?p=pages&id=3";   //FULL URl
```

How can I do it.. Please note that, the directory `calvin` can change according to where user decides, he/she can even place script in child directories. eg. instead of `calvin` can be `myweb/scripts/this_script`

Comment: `$fullURL = $second . $first;` ? - You'd might need to check whether the two variables contain overlapping parts, but that's a matter of regex or searching the strings.

Comment: Can I assume that it's always the first part of `$first` and the last part of `$second`? like `/part/` is a part separated by `/`?

Comment: What is `calvin` in `$first`. Will it always be same as in `$second`? So that `http://localhost/calvin/` becomes `http://localhost/myweb/` and `/calvin/master/?p=pages&id=3` becomes `/myweb/master/?p=pages&id=3`. Or?

Comment: Yes @AshishChoudhary that is the directory user select to place the script..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do :

```
<?php


$first = "/calvin/master/?p=pages&id=3";
$second = "http://localhost/calvin/";

//First we explode both string to have array which are easier to compare
$firstArr = explode('/', $first);
$secondArr = explode('/', $second);

//Then we merged those array and remove duplicata
$fullArray = array_merge($secondArr,$firstArr);
$fullArray = array_unique($fullArray);

//And we put all back into a string
$fullStr = implode('/', $fullArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$first_array =split("/" , $first);
$second_array =split("/" , $second);

$url = $second; //use the entire beginning

if($second_array[count($second_array) - 1] == $first_array[0]) { //check if they are the same
    for ($x = 1; $x <= count($first_array); $x++) { //add parts from the last part skipping the very first part
       $url .= "/" .$first_array[$x];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`$target = $second . str_replace(parse_url($second)['path'], '', $first);`

`parse_url` will break the `$second` URL to obtain the path after the domain which is directory `calvin` in this case. We can then replace the path in the `$first` to remove duplicate directory path. and then can append the remaining `$first` path without the directory to the `$second` path with the directory.